# What happens if I screw up the order of loops in the Floyd-Warshall algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory, floyd-warshall

For the Floyd-Warshall's algorithm, the order of the loops is k, i, and j. What happens if I screw up the order of the loops and accidentally write it as i, k, and j? In what way will the program not work? Thanks!

Comment: You get the Woyd-Flarshall algorithm, which produces dangerously bad jokes about computer science.

Comment: An interesting bit of trivia is that the algorithm will still be correct, as long as you run it three times (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.01210).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. it gives you the result if you aren't tampering with that 3-level iteration during run-time. Floyd-Warshall always returns the shortest paths there are.